# Handling long running database calls in nodejs

Tags: node.js, database, express, backend, jobs

I have an endpoint which send out response to client and based on response I want to do database calls(creating data of users)? How to achieve this **after sending out response**?

```
router.post('/',(req,res) => {
  Policy.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id, isActive: true }, { $set: req.body }, { new:true })
 .then(result => {
      // here i do not want to block the client so sending response
      res.status(200).json({message: 'Action taken Successfully'})
     /* After policy gets approved, My task here is to fetch all the list of 
        users and create data(policy data) for them so that they can fetch the policies and take action. */
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Of course you can call it asynchronously. Just call it before/after sending the response. But you can't send the headers again, it will generate errors.

Try the following code:

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    Policy.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id, isActive: true }, { $set: req.body }, { new:true })
        .then(result => {
            res.status(200).json({message: 'Action taken Successfully'});
            your_function_to_execute_other_operations();
        });
});
```

The above code will immediately send response after executing the `res.send`. After that, it will take care of the `your_function_to_execute_other_operations` function.

Comment: Hi @Sherin, Thanks for your response.I am having  doubt -
 your_function_to_execute_other_operations()  // will be inserting row in a table for users around 50k-60k users.
1-If I  call this (your_function_to_execute_other_operations()) after ending the response and 
   if any error occurs then how can I handle this? 
2-Is this db call going to affect the performance of other requests?